# Configure VIm to use Python using vim-bootstrap

Tags: python, vim

How does one configure *VIm* to use *Python* using [vim-bootstrap](http://vim-bootstrap.com)?

Comment: In what way do you want Vim to use Python?  If you want it to be able to interpret & run Python statements, that has to be set when compiling Vim, not in your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Access [Site](http://vim-bootstrap.com)
2. Click on **Make your .vimrc now!**
3. Select your languages: **Python**
4. Select Vim Editor
5. Click on **Generate!**
6. Download generete.vim
7. mv ~/Downloads/generate.vim ~/.vimrc
8. Execute ViM and it will install plugins automatically
9. vim +PlugInstall +qall

Open